# Is there an infinite series that converges to 1/q?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

im trying to find an example of an infinite series that converges to some $\frac{1}{q}$, where $q\in\mathbb{N}$. The only condition is that $a_k$>0 for all $k$. Can someone please give me an example, preferably a simple one. I believe there is but I can't remember right now.

Comment: $a_n = 1/q - 1/n$ for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Find a series that converges to a value $\alpha$, and multiply each term by $1/q\alpha$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 series, not sequence.

Comment: Set $a_1=1/q$ and $a_k=0$ for all $k > 1$.

Comment: Oh okey. i must add the condition that all $a_k$ should be positive

Comment: Like Arturo points out these really aren't hard to find but one that I like is $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k + q} - \frac{1}{k + q + 1},$ which we can rewrite as $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac1{(k+q)(k+q+1)}$ if you want to hide the telescoping a bit. Otherwise a simple geometric series like $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac1{q \cdot 2^k}$ or $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac1{(q - 1)^k}$ (for $q \neq 1$) should do, yea? (although for the first I've certainly used Arturo's construction)

Comment: @StephenDonovan thankyou

Comment: For $|r| < 1,$ you have that $$\displaystyle r + r^2 +r^3 + \cdots = \frac{r}{1-r} = \frac{1}{q}.$$  This implies that $$rq = 1-r \implies r(q+1) = 1 \implies r = \frac{1}{q+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The geometric series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n $$ converges to $\frac{x}{1-x}$, so, if you set this value to be equal to $\frac{1}{q}$, you get $x=\frac{1}{q+1} \ $.

So, the series you are looking for is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(q+1)^n} \ .$$